# Synchronize 2 IP camera RTSP Streams

Tags: h.264, sync, multi-camera

So we have 2 IP camera RTSP streams that we are saving to disk. At some point we stop the recording on both streams and go back to N frames in each video.

The problem that we are facing is that the Nth frame in video 1 does not point to the same instance as that of the Nth frame in video 2. Basically they are out of sync by X frames. This problem occurs because both cameras are not emitting frames at constant 60 fps and their actual fps usually varies b/w 58-60. Over time this variable difference in fps leads to greater out of sync behavior.

How can I overcome this out of sync behavior without going the hardware route (genlocking etc etc).
I do not have much understanding of ONVIF, can that be of any help here?